# Need help with setting up a filter for a view (sharepoint UI only)

Tags: filter

I need help setting up a and/or filter and I can't seem to get it right.

Its based off dates.  I am looking for the following:

> Between (StartDate-Status1 and EndDate-Status1)
>
> OR
>
> Between (StartDate-Status2 and EndDate-Status2)
>
> OR
>
> Between (StartDate-Status3 and EndDate-Status3)
>
> AND
>
> Not equal to "Value1"

So it must be within any of the Status values AND above all else, it must not equal to `Value1`

Hope this makes sense.

I just need to know how to setup the AND/OR precedence...

Answer (score 0):

All of your filters will need the: AND Not equal to "Value1"

And it appears you are missing the field/value/column you are comparing against those dates, I'm calling it "Date looking at" in my example below

so it would be:

`Date looking at:
is greater than or equal to
StartDate-Status1
AND
Date looking at
is less than or equal to
EnDDate-Status1
AND
Date looking at
is not equal to
Value1
OR
Date Looking at
is greater than or equal to
StartDate-Status2
AND
date looking at
is less than or equal to
EndDate-Status2
AND date looking at
is not equal to
Value1
OR
date looking at
is greater than or equal to
StartDate-Status3
AND
date looking at 
is less than or equal to
EndDate-Status3
AND
Date looking at
is not equal to
Value1`

I believe you can have a total of 10 conditions.. that is 9 right there, if you need more than that I have had to create other columns to hold those conditions which I update via workflow